# Is there an archive of closed-form mutual information among the "famous" distributions?

Tags: references, mutual-information

I'm looking for a **document or compilation table of closed-form** mutual information as a function of their parameters, for known distributions such as normal, gamma, Poisson distributions.

At least, I would like to check the shape of mutual information as a function of their parameters .

Anyone to introduce me some source?